# Show appbar after scroll - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have to display app bar only after user has scrolled a certain extent.

```dart
AnimationController _colorAnimation,
Animation _colorTween,

bool _scrollListener(ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
    if (scrollInfo.metrics.axis == Axis.vertical) {
      _colorAnimation.animateTo(scrollInfo.metrics.pixels / 260);
    }
    return true;
}

// In init func
...
  _colorAnimation =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0));
  _colorTween = ColorTween(begin: Colors.transparent, end: bgColor)
        .animate(_colorAnimation);
...

//AppBar
AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _colorTween,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
             backgroundColor: _colorTween.value,
          ),
      ),
)
```

This worked fine, except now in the `body` I have an `ExpansionTile`. And when user scrolls to the bottom and collapses the tile, I get an error.

```
If, on the other hand, the one frame delay is the desired effect, for example because this is an animation, consider scheduling the frame in a post-frame callback using SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback or using an AnimationController to trigger the animation.
```

```
FlutterError (Build scheduled during frame. While the widget tree was being built, laid out, and painted, a new frame was scheduled to rebuild the widget tree...
```

This error occurs here, in `.animateTo` (`_scrollListener` function)

```dart
 _colorAnimation.animateTo(scrollInfo.metrics.pixels / 260);
```